# PHPmailer not sending a message

Tags: php, phpmailer

I tried to use SMTP with google and yahoo..even uploading the script to a host and not using smtp..and also running the script on my local machine.

Here is the script:

```
 require_once './PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';
    require_once './PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'alforce@gmail.com';                            // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '?q$';     
    $mail->Port= 465;
    $mail->SMTPDebug=1;
    // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
    $mail->Timeout=350;
    $mail->From = 'alforce@gmail.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'alforce';
    $mail->addAddress('infkot@clnt.co.il', 'Clgent');  // Add a recipient


                                   // Set word wrap to 50 characters
    $mail->addAttachment('nbproject.rar');         // Add attachments


    $mail->Subject = 'Spdddd';
    $mail->Body    = 'Dsdssdds';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
       echo 'Message could not be sent.';
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
    }

    echo 'Message has been sent';
```

I get this:

```
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) SMTP connect() failed. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE ..it has worked. I reduced the attachment size and played with the parameters..I changed the tls to ssl.

Now when I put the code in a loop I get this errors:

> Warning: fwrite(): SSL: The operation completed successfully. in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\PHPMailer-master\class.smtp.php on line 803

and at the end I get 3 more message of this before the script dies

> Warning: fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1409F07F:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_PENDING:bad write retry in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\PHPMailer-master\class.smtp.php on line 803

Why?

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: Have a look at the following answer on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer

Comment: whats the size of the attachment you are trying to send ??

Comment: Well. I sent it with an without an attachement. The problem is google smtp.. I was able to send a normal email and an email with attachment..but the smpt..is rejective

Comment: Gmail uses SSL not TLS