# email not going through using the mail() function

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I've got a form page on my website where the user has to enter his email ID. As soon as he does that an email should get triggered to him. I've used the mail() function but the email isn't going through. This is on a remote server. Am I missing out on something? Below is the PHP code that I'm using.

```
<?php
$to  = 'xyz@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Demo mail';
$message = 'This is a demo mail. Please reply to make sure the mail communication is okay.';
$headers = 'From: abc@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: abc@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
   echo("<p>Email successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Email delivery failed</p>");
  }
?>
```

The output is Email delivery failed!
What is it that I'm supposed to do apart from this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you trying this on localhost?

Comment: Maybe helpful for [sending local mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149535/send-mail-from-local-apache-server)

Comment: @Sudhir the mail() function isn't working...so the mail ain't going through

Comment: @sunny No. I'm trying this on a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

`mail()` function relies on email configuration of the server the program is running on. You should take a look at your server email configuration, or use a library in order to hook up with an external SMTP service, like Gmail or one of your email servers. I recommend the Swift email library, which is well known, it's thoroughly tested and has a great community behind:

http://swiftmailer.org/

Answer (score 0):

check php.ini config file for SMTP connection or add ini_set("SMTP", "IP_ADDRESS"); in your script.

you can also wrap your script with a error handler to debug the SMTP connection.