# Yii, Yiimailer doesn't send the mail (no error shown)

Tags: php, yii

i'm trying to send a mail. i want to use Gmail server to send, for now i just want it to send to the same account from its being sent.

i'm using YiiMailer extension because it seems to be easy to use, this is the action i have in my controller:

```
public function actionContact()
    {
        $model=new ContactForm;
        if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];
            if($model->validate())
            {
                $name='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->name).'?=';
                $subject='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->subject).'?=';
                $headers="From: $name <{$model->email}>\r\n".
                    "Reply-To: {$model->email}\r\n".
                    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
                    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";

                // mail(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'],$subject,$model->body,$headers);

                $mail = new YiiMailer('contact', array(
                    'message'=>$model->body,
                    'name'=>$model->name,
                    'description'=>'Contact form'
                ));

                $mail->setFrom($model->email, $model->name);
                $mail->setSubject($model->subject);
                $mail->setTo(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail']);

                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                $mail->port = 465;
                $mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
                $mail->Password = "password";

                if($mail->send())
                {
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Gracias por contactarnos, te responderemos tan pronto como podamos.');
                    $this->refresh();
                }

                else
                {
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error','Error enviando correo.');
                    $this->refresh();
                }
            }
        }
        $this->render('contact',array('model'=>$model));
    }
```

the adminMail is the same like account@gmail.com

i dont't know if i have the right settings for gmail, i'm sure the condition of the function doesn't exist so it does nothing.

just to make sure. this is my config:

```
// autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'ext.YiiMailer.YiiMailer'
    ),
```

PD: i found the gmail settings around post. i'm not sure if they changed the settings.

Answer (score 2):

Try using method `getError()` to find out what the error was (you can use special debug options to get more information on possible errors)

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; //optional

if($mail->send())
{
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Gracias por contactarnos, te responderemos tan pronto como podamos.');
    $this->refresh();
}
else
{
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($mail->getError());
    echo '</pre>';
    exit;
}
```

Additionaly, try the following:

- ADD `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'`; or `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`
- ADD `$mail->SMTPAuth = true;`

This question could interest you: [send email using Gmail SMTP server through PHP Mailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer)

Comment: it wont do anything about it, if() nor else() is going.. it just takes like 5 secs, and then refreshes the page with no flash.

Comment: I've edited my code: use var_dump and then exit - that will stop PHP from continuing.

Comment: gave me : SMTP Connect() failed.

Comment: Add `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;`. That'll give you more information on what your problem is.

Comment: hm, now i'm entirely sure i don't know this error: SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061) SMTP Connect() failed

Comment: Maybe the port is blocked on your firewall?

Comment: the firewall is disabled and still gives me the error. maybe gmail doesnt use 465 port anymore..

Comment: Or maybe you need to use SSL (don't forget to enable SSL extension for PHP as well)? Anyway, there's more info for you to search on the Internet now =)

Comment: php_openssl is enabled in my php, still not clue how to fix it, i'm looking in google's api

Comment: i've checked everything, but it gives me the same error.

Comment: i guess i found the error. the php_smtp is not being enabled, and i dont know why, i'm using wamp and i had to download that extension, i try many times to enable it, but it doesnt.

Comment: i'll just forget about this.. there's no way i can fix the php_smtp for wamp, so i won't be able to send emails.. thanks for the help..

Comment: Ok. Sorry I was not able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me!

```
            $mail = new YiiMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup server
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = 'username';                            // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
            $mail->Port = 587;
                        //set mail properties
            $mail->setFrom('username@gmail.com', 'YYY');

        $mail->setTo($model->to_email);

        $mail->setSubject($model->subject);
        $mail->setBody($model->message, 'text/html');

        $mail->send();
```

You need to set the `smtpauth` to `true` when using Gmail to send email.Ckeck your sendMail box after executing the action!

Comment: can you tell me what server are you using?. cause i cannot make this in wamp, php_smtp is no longer compatible.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by install stunnel, so openssl is enabled and let me send emails from my server