# error bool(false) when use var_dump($mail->send()); at phpmailer

Tags: php, yii, phpmailer

```
$mail = new YiiMailer();
$mail->setView('contact');
$mail->setData(array('register' => $model,'user' =>$user));
//$mail->clearLayout();//if layout is already set in config
$mail->setFrom('xxxx@gmail.com', 'amatra');
$mail->setTo($model->client_email);
$mail->setSubject('Amatra Registration');
$mail->setBody('Thank u for registering, to get server licence activation key ');
$mail->setSmtp('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl', true, 'xxxx@gmail.com', 'aconxontheroad');

var_dump($mail->send());
if($mail->send()) {
    return true;    
} else {
    return false;
}
```

I changed port and SMTPSecure but still outputs `bool (false)`,I can't deduce where the error is.

Comment: In order to see errors, you need to do some actual error checking, and make use of PHPMailer’s debugging features, which you will find in the docs and examples. This code attempts to send your message twice, once for each time you call `send`.

Comment: CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2018-10-08 00:23:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2018-10-08 00:23:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: bGFzdGthZ2FtaTYyQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ== 2018-10-08 00:23:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: a2FnYW1p 2018-10-08 00:23:21 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials t15-v6sm41674857pfj.7 - gsmtp 2018-10-08 00:23:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT SMTP Connect() failed

Comment: So read the page that links to, and [read the PHPMailer docs that tell you what to do about it](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#read-the-smtp-transcript). You set `SMTPDebug = 1`, so you can't see all that the server is saying; set it to `2`. It also looks like you're using a very old version of PHPMailer, so you should update.

Comment: i changed SMTPDebug=2

Comment: 2018-10-08 00:49:15 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP z22-v6sm16576242pgk.21 - gsmtp 2018-10-08 00:49:15

Comment: i find it,,if update is wil be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; //optional
```

You can refer this post to clearly:
[Yii, Yiimailer doesn't send the mail (no error shown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463333/yii-yiimailer-doesnt-send-the-mail-no-error-shown)

Comment: Set this to 2, not 1. Also this should be a comment as it’s not an answer.

Comment: it's runing for chaking error
the erros is
2018-10-08 00:23:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2018-10-08 00:23:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2018-10-08 00:23:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: bGFzdGthZ2FtaTYyQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ== 2018-10-08 00:23:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: a2FnYW1p 2018-10-08 00:23:21 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials t15-v6sm41674857pfj.7 - gsmtp 2018-10-08 00:23:21 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT SMTP Connect() failed.

Comment: username and password was true,,and i setting gmails to less secure
but still error

Answer (score 0):

Try the Yii2 Swift mailer.

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('contact/html')
 ->setFrom('from@domain.com')
 ->setTo($form->email)
 ->setSubject($form->subject)
 ->send();
```

https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer