# send email on server

Tags: php, email

I set up SMTP and smtp_port in php.ini file. And it's already there.

```
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","465");
```

Now, I am trying to send email by this:

```
$to      = 'email@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: email@example2.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: email@example2.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

**ERROR:**

```
Message: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at
                 "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" port 465, verify your "SMTP" and
                 "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

Is this because of authentication problem? I don't want to use `PHPMailer`.

Comment: You may find some help here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer.

Comment: thanks @Zeratops. But, I want to use default email functionality in PHP. Not `PHPMailer`

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide your gmail crendentials (login and password) to send mail via google smtp server
the php `mail()` function does not provide this feature
i advise you to download and use this PHP Project : https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer
With it you can do everything : gmail credentials, attach files, write mail with HTML....
Hope that helps :)

Comment: That's an unofficial fork, better to use the official one https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer