# Website contact Form Problems

Tags: html, forms

Firstly I've searched current thread's and tried 99% of the working fixes provided by the community,

My problem is i am receiving no email's via

> www.vapescotts.co.uk

This contact form is placed at the bottom, The odd thing is the website is an altered version of a working website. So I'm clueless to why this version don't work.

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<table width="100%">
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="first_name"><p>First Name</p></label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="50">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top"">
<label for="last_name"><p>Last Name</p></label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="50">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="email"><p>Email Address</p></label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="50">
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="telephone"><p>Telephone Number</p></label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="50">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments"><p>Your Comments</p></label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="38" rows="12"></textarea>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:left">
<input type="image" src="submit.png" input type="submit" value="Submit" height: "251px"; width: "293px"></i> 

</td> </td>
</tr></tr>
</table></table>
</form></form>
</div> </div>
```

And here is the html_form_send.php configuration

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "vapescotts@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "Scotts Custard Cream Enquiry";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

Thank you for your enquiry, Redirecting back to Scott's Custard Cream.
<br />If you are not redirected automatically,<a href='http://www.vapescotts.co.uk'>Click Here</a>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.vapescotts.co.uk" /> 
<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Thank's again to the StackOverflow Community.

Comment: Are you trying to run the code locally or the pages are hosted on web ?

Comment: The pages are on the web, Hope this helps

Comment: Are you getting specific error or the page just goes blank ?

Comment: By the way, don't use @mail, just use mail()

Comment: Do you have access to php.ini? Is PHP configured to send email?

Comment: this could well be the problem im with 1&1 and the is no php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

some servers block mail function better to try SMTP PHP Mailer.

Here we go [send email using Gmail SMTP server through PHP Mailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, might help you out. Edit this code as per your convenience.

```
$to = "webmaster@example.com";
$subj = "Contact Form Request";
$body = "There is a new contact form report, Kindly check it out.";
$body .= "<table border='1' cellpadding='5'>";
$body .= "<tr><td>Name:</td><td>".$name."</td></tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td>Email:</td><td>".$email."</td></tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td>Subject:</td><td>".$subject."</td></tr>";
$body .= "<tr><td>Message:</td><td>".$msg."</td></tr>";
$body .= "</table>";

$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . strip_tags($email) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$succ = mail( $to, $subj, $body, $headers );

if ( $succ || $succ != '' ) {
    echo "Mail Sent";
} else {
    echo "Failed";
}
```