# Send mail to a mailing list in php

Tags: php, email

My friend has got a e-commerce website where users can choose to receive mail with the new offers. So he asked to me to create a system to send them an email.

How can I with php send an email to all the people in the mailing list?
I know that editing the php.ini  I can send mail from my personal email, like GMAIL, but it has a maximum number of mails for day.

So what is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is with SMTP.

http://www.jvfconsulting.com/blog/php-mail-function-vs-smtp-guaranteed-delivery/ explains that the standard php `mail` function sends mail, but your mails can be heavily blocked by anti-spam mechanisms of ISPs.

There are many prebuilt solutions, PHPMailer being one of them.  Please see this link as well: [send email using Gmail SMTP server through PHP Mailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer)

Comment: Thank's for answering. I'm looking for PHPMailer, but i think that I have to look also for an email that allow me to send more than 200 email for days like Gmail. is it right?

Comment: Using phpmailer you can send directly using php defaul mail function which does not require any email.

Comment: If you're looking to send a large volume of mail, you should do some research into a 3rd-party application `mailing list` tool perhaps.