# Php mailer body is empty

Tags: php, phpmailer

Iam using PHP mailer to send an Email the message sent but email body is Empty

here is my code

```
foreach($results as $result)
{

    $email = $result['email'];

    $body = 'Hello'.$result['username'].' we remind you to return the book to library after' .$result['days'];

    $mail = new PHPMailer; 
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'mail.myhost.com;'; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'send@myhost.com';
    $mail->Password = 'mypassword';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;

    $mail->From = 'send@myhost.com'; 
    $mail->FromName ='Bookstore'; 
    $mail->addAddress($email, 'username');
    $mail->Subject = 'Book returned Time'; 
    $mail->Body = $body; 
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    if(!$mail->send()) { 
        echo 'Message could not be sent.'; 
        //echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo; return $user ; 
    } else { 
        echo 'done'; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Sidenote: please don't use `>` characters for code. Paste your code in the editor then select all, and hit CTRL-K and save.

Comment: People still use that library?

Comment: @Flosculus why not ?

Comment: @Flosculus any suggested library to send mail ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- 

Sorry i didn't notice

Comment: It maybe help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer

Comment: Since you're sending to a list, base your code on [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).