# What to do when server don't support SMTP and mail?

Tags: php, smtp, server, phpmailer

I check now my server support, they say that they currently don't support SMTP, and also mail() function won't work.

I see that some wordpress plugins, as newsletter plugin can send mails, some others can't, and also i can't send mail outside wordpress.

What i can to do?
If there is some free smtp server how can i configure it to phpmailer script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send email using Gmail SMTP server through PHP Mailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer)

Comment: Ok, i see that i can use gmail smtp. I added an email account in accounts and import, and now i don't know what username and password i need to use in phpmailer credentials? Username and password of that email i added or?

Comment: General rule is not to rely on the host server for SMTP support.  Off load it to another system, or service.

Comment: Use your gmail username & password

Comment: When i use gmail username and password i get SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 435 4.7.8 Error: authentication failed:

Comment: Use the gmail examples provided with PHPMailer, and [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki).