# PHPmailer With Gmail Error

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using PHP Mailer to send email from Gmail via my PHP code,

here is my PHPMailer Configuration :

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->Username = 'baliwisata.email@gmail.com';  
$mail->Password = 'SECRET !';   

$mail->From = 'baliwisata.email@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Bali Wisata';
$mail->addAddress($companyEmail);
$mail->addReplyTo($this->email);

$mail->isHTML(true);
```

And it return a super Long Message can be seen here :

http://textuploader.com/52kcm

Can Somebody Help Me Please ?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send email using Gmail SMTP server through PHP Mailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer)

Comment: @Nikunj Both way no help T.T

Comment: then you need to check your firewall setting it's might be effect your client-server request and response