# PHP Mailer doesn't send mail and not loading errors on my server

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHP MAiler but the mail is not being sent,In fact the website on my server just keeps on loading and loading w/o showing any error.I even changed my gmail settings to allow less secure app but still the page doesnt load nor does it show any errors.
Code:

```
<?php 
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

  $mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'mohd.gadiwala@techmatters.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('mohd.gadiwala@techmatters.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('mohd.gadiwala@techmatters.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    // Optional name
// $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}


 ?>
```

I have Php mailer folder in the same folder as this so I guess loading the file isn't the problem

Comment: Can you verify if the email was not *sent* or was not *received*? There is a difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer may help you.

Comment: first, try to connect with your credentials and config some another smtp client (theBat, outlook, etc), and if it's can connect to server - check your PHP code.

Comment: I tried changing to ssl doesnt work