# Mailer Error: SMTP() requires user credentials

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

I have a system where when the user registers, system will send an email to the user with activation link. I am doing this process using  SMTP connect(). But it asks for user's credentials ( with password) to whom I want to send the email, *which makes no sense in the production level.* How can I do this without knowing the user credentials?

Comment: What other parameters are you setting? Are you setting the SMTP server correctly for each domain?

Comment: $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
                $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
                $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                $mail->Port = 465; // or 587


I think they are correct

Comment: So are all the emails coming from Gmail accounts? The SMTP credentials that they enter will only be valid for a particular server, based on their email provider.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send email using Gmail SMTP server through PHP Mailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been covered many times on here - gmail doesn't allow you to send from arbitrary addresses, and asking for user's credentials to allow sending from their account is just bonkers; nobody should *ever* do that. Don't send from the user; send from your own address and use the submitter's address as a reply-to address. That way you only need your own credentials and will not be forging the from address.