# trying to reset password using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to create a forget password webpage using PHP and JS. Although when I try add an email address, and click "reset password" nothing happens, and there are no errors in the console. What I want is for the text to appear so the user knows if their password has been reset. But nothing happens and I am unsure what the problem is. If anyone has any ideas can you please let me know. Thanks

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require_once "functions.php";

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  require_once('config1.php');

    $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);


    $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM zz_login WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $token = generateNewString();

        $sql = "UPDATE zz_login SET token='$token',
                            tokenExpire=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
                            WHERE email='$email' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

        require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
        require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->addAddress($email);
        $mail->setFrom("", "");
        $mail->Subject = "Reset Password";
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = "
            Hi,<br><br>

            In order to reset your password, please click on the link below:<br>
            <a href='
            URL/resetPassword.php?email=$email&token=$token
            '>URL/resetPassword.php?email=$email&token=$token</a><br><br>

            Kind Regards,<br>
            Trip Guider
        ";

        if ($mail->send())
            exit(json_encode(array("status" => 1, "msg" => 'Please Check Your Email Inbox!')));
        else
            exit(json_encode(array("status" => 0, "msg" => 'Something Wrong Just Happened! Please try again!')));
    } else
        exit(json_encode(array("status" => 0, "msg" => 'Please Check Your Inputs!')));
}
?>
```

Javascript

```
alert(response);
response= $.parseJSON(response);
if (!response.status)

var email = $("#email");

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn-primary').on('click', function () {
            if (email.val() != "") {
                email.css('border', '1px solid green');

                $.ajax({
                   url: 'forgotPassword.php',
                   method: 'POST',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   data: {
                       email: email.val()
                   }, success: function (response) {
                        if (!response.success)
                            $("#response").html(response.msg).css('color', "red");
                        else
                            $("#response").html(response.msg).css('color', "green");
                    }
                });
            } else
                email.css('border', '1px solid red');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Request sent to server ? If yes show the server response.

Comment: @4EACH I am not sure what you mean, could you explain

Comment: What do you get when you run `console.log(email);` or `console.log(email.val());`

Comment: Use rest client to demonstrate post request and make sure that the server side works as you expect. Next step is to check in browser -> developer tools -> network that you sending the request from client as you expecting.

Comment: @Thefourthbird nothing appears when i add either of them. When I click the button in the network it doesn't show the forgotPassword.php. Is it meant to?

Comment: Are you sure you pass this statement? `if (email.val() != "") {`

Comment: @Thefourthbird  I am getting this error now <b>Warning</b>: mysqli_num_rows(): Function cannot be used with MYSQL_USE_RESULT in <b>URL <b>13</b><br />e 13 is if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { –

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the json output in jQuery with the following lines:

```
response= $.parseJSON(response);
  if (!response.status)
```

Then you can check for the `status` variable value i.e. whether it is 1 or 0 according to your `json_encode`d variable in PHP. Also make sure that `$mail->send()` actualls succeeds in sending the email. Depending on the server (localhost or online) settings, it may not always work.

```
var email = $("#email");

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn-primary').on('click', function () {
            if (email.val() != "") {
                email.css('border', '1px solid green');

                $.ajax({
                   url: 'forgotPassword.php',
                   method: 'POST',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   data: {
                       email: email.val()
                   }, success: function (response) {
                       response= $.parseJSON(response);
                        if (!response.status)
                          $("#response").html(response.msg).css('color', "red");
                        else
                            $("#response").html(response.msg).css('color', "green");
                    }
                });
            } else
                email.css('border', '1px solid red');
        });
    });
```

**Edit:**
try sending the email using SMTP.
Pasting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16048485/998537),

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SetFrom("example@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("email@gmail.com");

 if(!$mail->Send()) {

  // do your stuff
 } else {
    // do your stuff
 }
```

The example above uses gmail's smtp. If you use any other mailing service to send the email from, change the values of `$mail->Host` and `$mail->Port`  accordingly

Comment: I am getting this error <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_num_rows(): Function cannot be used with MYSQL_USE_RESULT in <b>URL <b>13</b><br />e 13 is if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

Comment: @CD6554M use ` $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` instead of ` $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);` in PHP code.

Comment: It is now coming up with the error <b>Warning</b>:  Your version of PHP is affected by a bug that may result in corrupted messages. To fix it, switch to sending using SMTP, disable the mail.add_x_header option in your php.ini, switch to MacOS or Linux, or upgrade your PHP to version 7.0.17+ or 7.1.3+. in <b>URL</b> on line <b>1364</b><br /> I have never seen an error like that before

Comment: @CD6554, Edit added

Comment: Thanks, although what do I change the username, password and SetFrom to? I want it so that when the user logs in, it knows who they are, rather than hard coding an email address into the php

Comment: You need to change them according to your gmail address if you are using gmail to send the mail

Comment: So the username is my email address that I want to send it to, the password is the password for my gmail account, and the SetFrom is my email address again?

Comment: ok so its now saying Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined on this line response= $.parseJSON(response);

Comment: before that line just add `alert(response);` and let me know what happens

Comment: it didn't do anything, an alert didnt come up

Comment: @CD6554, paste the full `success` callback function here

Comment: I don't know what that is.. Do you have discord, just aware that this is a lot of messages under one question

Comment: just thought it would be easier to talk to on that, or skype or something. I updated my question with the js code, although it looks exactly the same as yours

Comment: @CD6554, you are not using my JS code as I see in your question

Comment: I am, how is yours differerent?

Comment: You cannot find these 2 lines `response= $.parseJSON(response);
                        if (!response.status)` in your question

Comment: they are at the top of the code, where am i supose to put them?

Comment: @CD6554, OMG, just delete everything inside your js file and then paste the code I gave in my answer . I mean the big JS code snippet I gave

Comment: so i dont need the 
response= $.parseJSON(response);
  if (!response.status) lines?

Comment: You do not need to add it the way you did

Comment: that is what i asked previously, where do i put that piece of code?

Comment: Can you please reply to me

Comment: i did do that, but where do i put the response= $.parseJSON(response); if (!response.status)???????

Comment: no where to put. that is already here `success: function (response) {
                        response= $.parseJSON(response);
                        if (!response.status)
                            $("#response").html(response.msg).css('color', "red");
                        else
                            $("#response").html(response.msg).css('color', "green");
                    }`inside the `$.ajax`

Comment: I am getting these errors now 

<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP' not found in D:\ URL\PHPMailer.php:1687
Stack trace:
#0 D:\URL\PHPMailer.php(1812): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer-&gt;getSMTPInstance()
#1 D:\URLPHPMailer.php(1725): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer-&gt;smtpConnect(Array)
#2 DURL\PHPMailer.php(1481): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer-&gt;smtpSend('Date: Sun, 25 F...', ' Hi,&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;\r\n\t...')
#3 D:\URL\PHPMailer.php(1320): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer-&gt;po in <b>D:\URL\PHPMailer.php</b> on line <b>1687</b><br />

Comment: I looked at this but i don't understand any of the answers,  they arent the same problem as mine. This is the part of the code that isnt wotking public function getSMTPInstance()
    {
        if (!is_object($this->smtp)) {
            $this->smtp = new SMTP();
        }

        return $this->smtp;
    }

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Uncaught+Error%3A+Class+%27PHPMailer%5CPHPMailer%5CSMTP%27+not+found+in+PHPMailer.php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab

Answer (score 0):

It should be very easy to debug what is happening with the following tools:

- Firefox Debugger Tab in Developer Tools
- Firefox Network Tab in Developer tools,
- xdebug for php

With Developer Tools Firefox Network tab, you should be able to look in the sub tab 'xhr' and see all outgoing requests. You can see the outbound data and the response from the server.

With the Debugger, you can step through your JavaScript and check that your logic is good.

With xdebug for php, you can step through your php code when the request hits your server and make sure the logic is good on that end.

Please use your Developer Tools!

Comment: I am using my developer tools, I am getting this error <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP' not found in D:URL\php\PHPMailer\PHPMailer.php:1687 but I am not sure how to fix it

Comment: Oh that is coming from your 'require_once' statement

Comment: The file is not being found.

Comment: The class PHPMailer is trying to include a class SMTP, but it can not find it. You need to make sure the SMTP class/file can be found.

Comment: How can I do that? I don't really understand it

Comment: Actually, I think the problem is that your namespace statement is wrong.

Comment: use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; is not the correct namespace.

Comment: I just went through the whole file in PHPMailer and there was nothing like 'require_once PHPMailer\SMTP.php'

Comment: What is the name space statement?

Comment: use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

Comment: In replace of what though?

Comment: Just delete that line entirely.

Comment: and put all of your require_once statements at the top of your page

Comment: and you need to define your own namespace. Put     namespace ResetPassword;    as the very first line of code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165795/discussion-between-cd6554-and-keith-becker).