# Send email using SMTP in PHP with PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, magento2.2

I tryed this code:

```
<?php

// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load composer's autoloader
require '/home/username/public_html/vendor/autoload.php';



/**
     * @param type $array
     * @param type $int
     * @return type
     */
    function send_mail_customer($nickname, $email, $total_value)
    {
        $to      = $email;
        $subject = 'DISTRIBUIÇÃO DE LUCRO: ' . $nickname ;

        $from = "myname@mydomain.com";
        $name = $nickname;

        $message = "<html><body>";
        $message .= "<H1> DISTRIBUIÇÃO MENSAL DE LUCRO </H1>";
        $message .= "<strong>Total ganho:</strong> " .$total_value. " euros";
        $message .= "</body></html>";


        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
        try {
            //Server settings
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
            $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'mail.mydomain.com';                   // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = 'Myname@mydomain.com';          // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = 'Mypassword';                       // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
            $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to 587

            //Recipients
            $mail->setFrom($from, 'MyDomain');
            $mail->addAddress($to, $nickname);     // Add a recipient
            //$mail->addAddress('contact@example.com');               // Name is optional
            $mail->addReplyTo($from, 'MyDomain');
            //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
            //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

            //Attachments
            //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
            //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

            //Content
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body    = $message;
            //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

            $mail->send();
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }

    }

    $x="NunoSousa";
    $email="myemail@gmail.com";
    $total_value = 15;
    send_mail_customer($x, $email, $total_value);

?>
```

And I receive the error:

> 2018-09-26 08:06:21 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) SMTP
>   connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message
>   could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

I read the wiki but I just can't see what's wrong. I tried also TLS encryption with the port 587 and the issue still the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send email using Gmail SMTP server through PHP Mailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

To

```
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
 $mail->Port = 587;
```

Comment: I used TLS in port 587 and it gives me the error: 26 Sep 2018 08:49:02 -0500 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Host is wrong. In my case my host is named `smtp.domain.com`.
Also i'm using `tls` with port `587`, you could try again to connect using correct host.

In your case that would be

```
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.mydomain.com';
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
 $mail->Port = 587;
```

Comment: I checked in cPanel. The host is mail.mydomain.com. With smtp.mydomain.com I receive the error: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)

Comment: Can you find out the smtp address? Typically the mail provider have an address like `smtp.domain.com`. Or can you find some other information about smtp there?

Comment: From the cPanel
POP/IMAP Server: mail.domain.com
SMTP Settings: mail.domain.com

Comment: Then it should working with `$mail->host = 'mail.domain.com'`, `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'` and `$mail->Port = 587`. Maybe you have to enable access from external to this mail account? I remember doing it at the mail provider web.de for accessing ans sending mail through this account by outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Your mail host, set to ip address of your server:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // Enable verbose debug output, default is 2
$mail->isSMTP();   // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = ''; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '';    // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '';    // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also 
                          //accepted
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Comment: I received an error: 2018-09-26 15:37:15 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)

Comment: @NunoSousa Updated answer, try that.

Comment: Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. :(