# I am using PHPMailer but mail not received in gmail

Tags: php

I received the mail continuously fine but suddenly I didn't receive any mail. I don't know what happened with my code also I didn't get any error in my error log file as well. I am using it on Godaddy server

```
$mails = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Username = "mymail@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "myPassword";
    $mail->From = "foo@gmail.com";
    $mail->FromName = "John Doe";
    $mail->AddAddress('foobar@foobar.com');

    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "John Doe Lead Update";

    $mail->Body = '
        <h2>Mahindra Campaign Data</h2>';

        if($mail->send()){

            echo 'Message sent';
        }
           else
         {
            echo 'Mailer error' .$mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
```

Comment: Are you using it on local or server  like godaddy?

Comment: This is not the PHP issue, it is a designing part

Comment: But when i use this code it's working fine but here i didn't add HTMl code      
         $to = "sourav.mudgil@vermmillion.net.in";
         $subject = "Mahindra Alturas Lead Update";
         $message = '<b>Mahindra Campaign Data</b>
                  
             $header = "From:sourav.mudgil@gmail.com \r\n";
         $retval = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
         if(isset($retval))//change
         {
             echo "Message sent successfully...";
         }
         else
         {
             echo "Message could not be sent...";
         }

Comment: Is the `From` address you are using actually different from the account you’re doing the SMTP authentication with here? Don’t do that, that is asking for trouble.

Comment: You may want to have a look at answer on this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-php-mailer

Comment: have you given permissions from ur gmail to sent mail from other sources??

Answer (score 0):

May be GoDaddy server issue. If you are using shared hosting, there will be some limitations for sending emails. You can use third party services like mailchimp or you can use Amazon email services.