# PHPMalier - SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Tags: php, phpmailer

Can you try the code Please?
Guess where I went wrong

````
    ```
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    try {
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true


            )
        );

        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "********@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "********";
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mail->Port = 587;

        $mail->setFrom("********@gmail.com", "My name");
        $mail->addAddress("********@gmail.com");
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = "Mailer Test";
        $mail->Body = "This is a Test";

        $mail->send();
        echo "Ok";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "No";
    }
    ```
````

There are two duplicate errors that are written twice in output :
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
what's the problem?
Can you write the modify code

Comment: Did you install PHP Mailer trough Composer in the command line? Many times when I install it I also got a messagge that I need to install also other packages to authenticate to a specific mail server, maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64969226/use-php-mailer-to-send-via-gmail-smtp-error) will help you

Comment: With `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2` you must be getting much more detailed information than that

Comment: Try not to use `require 'vendor/autoload.php'`. Use `require 'SMTP.php'` and `require 'PHPMailer.php'`, instead (assuming that both are in the same folder of your PHP file).

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above. If I instal PHPmailer through composer it tels me I need to install also other packages for the right authentication. I installed PHPmailer today again for a new project so I copied the lines it showed me.

```
phpmailer/phpmailer suggests installing hayageek/oauth2-yahoo (Needed for Yahoo XOAUTH2 authentication)
phpmailer/phpmailer suggests installing league/oauth2-google (Needed for Google XOAUTH2 authentication)
phpmailer/phpmailer suggests installing psr/log (For optional PSR-3 debug logging)
phpmailer/phpmailer suggests installing stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft (Needed for Microsoft XOAUTH2 authentication)
phpmailer/phpmailer suggests installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (To support UTF-8 if the Mbstring PHP extension is not enabled (^1.2))
```