# SMTP connect() failed. PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm using 000webhost server and I got an error while sending the email using PHPMailer, knowing that it works in localhost with `tls` and Port `587`

Here is my code

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Portfolio/mail/Exception.php';
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Portfolio/mail/PHPMailer.php';
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Portfolio/mail/SMTP.php';

if(isset($_POST['hdn-insert'])) {
    $data=array();
    $variables = array();
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email_from = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $query = @unserialize (file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'));
    $location = $query['city'] . ', ' . $query['country'] . '.';
    $year = date('Y');
    $variables['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $variables['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $variables['message'] = $_POST['message'];
    $variables['location'] = $location;
    $variables['year'] = $year;
    
    $template = file_get_contents('MailUI.html');
    
    foreach($variables as $key => $value)
    {
        $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value, $template);
    }
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // 0 = off (for production use) - 1 = client messages - 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // use $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com'); // if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
    $mail->Port = 587; // TLS only
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // ssl is deprecated
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'hazemcrunchy@gmail.com'; // email
    $mail->Password = '**********'; // password
    $mail->setFrom($email_from, $name); // From email and name
    $mail->addAddress('hazemsamiir196@gmail.com', 'Hazem El-behairy'); // to email and name
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->msgHTML($template); //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), __DIR__); //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
    $mail->AltBody = 'HTML messaging not supported'; // If html emails is not supported by the receiver, show this body
    // $mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png'); //Attach an image file
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                        'ssl' => array(
                            'verify_peer' => false,
                            'verify_peer_name' => false,
                            'allow_self_signed' => true
                        )
                    );
    if(!empty($name) && !empty($email_from) && !empty($subject) && !empty($message) && strlen($message) >= '8'){
        if(!ctype_space($name) && !ctype_space($email_from) && !ctype_space($subject) && !ctype_space($message)){
            if ($mail->send()){
                $data['status'] = 1;
            } else {
                $data['status'] = 0;
            }
            echo json_encode($data); 
        } else {
            $data['status'] = 0;
        }
    }
    else{
        $data['status'] = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

The error message is:

`SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting`

I hope you guys get me well.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60767225/2518525) might be of help?

Comment: Have you perhaps tried following the link you were given and reading [the applicable docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host), or perhaps [searching for this error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SMTP+connect%28%29+failed+PHPMailer)?