# Username and Password could not authenticate while using phpmailer on my gmail account

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

I have been trying to set up a welcome email using phpmailer. I am facing ***Username and Password not accepted*** and ***Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.*** Error.
My email and password are very simple no special characters were used, tried all possible solutions on stack overflow and other sites. **Disabled Unlock Captcha**, tried to allow access to less secure apps and whatnot.
The code is attached below.

Kindly help.
I apologize if this has been asked already, I need help, Thanks in Advance

```php
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
session_start();




if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_NAME', 'rakaposhi');


    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
    $pswd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,md5($_POST['pswd']));
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['phone']);

    $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(15));
    $timestamp;
    $status = "Inactive";


    

    $sql = "SELECT username FROM userdata WHERE username = '{$username}'";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "Username already exists";
        }
        else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (username, pswd, name, email,  phone, token, status)
            VALUES ('{$username}', '{$pswd}', '{$name}', '{$email}', '{$phone}', '{$token}', '{$status}')";

            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
              
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function


//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'backendt3@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '';      // Removed Password for security purpose hereSMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('backendt3@gmail.com', 'Rakaposhi');
    $mail->addAddress($email, $username);     //Add a recipient
    // $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               //Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('backendt3@gmail.com', 'Rakaposhi Information');
    // $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    // $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    // $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
    // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Welcome - Activation Link';
    $mail->Body    = 'Activate kr na bhai';
    $mail->AltBody = 'kr le bhai';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
                
            }
            else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
    }



// mysqli_close($conn);

// header("Location: index.php");

}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<body> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
<section class="vh-100">
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-11">
        <div class="card text-black" style="border-radius: 25px;">
          <div class="card-body p-md-5">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-5 order-2 order-lg-1">

                <p class="text-center h1 fw-bold mb-5 mx-1 mx-md-4 mt-4">Sign up</p>

                <form class="mx-1 mx-md-4" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">

                  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                      <input type="text" id="form3Example1c" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                      <input type="password" id="form3Example1c" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="pswd" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                      <input type="text" id="form3Example1c" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" name="name" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                      <input type="email" id="form3Example1c" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                      <input type="phone" id="form3Example1c" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  
                  <div class="form-check d-flex  mb-5">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckChecked" checked>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
                    I agree to <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>
                    </label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-4 mb-3 mb-lg-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register</button>
                  </div>

                </form>

              </div>
              <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-7 d-flex align-items-center order-1 order-lg-2">

                <img src="imgs/cover2.webp"
                  class="img-fluid" alt="Sample image">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<br><br><br><br></div>
    </div>


    <!-- JS Popper Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is this problem really related to MySQL? Can you rule that out and remove the irrelevant parts of your code from the question? Also, be warned that your `INSERT` query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: AFAIK Google does not allow "less secure apps" any more. You need to implement XOAUTH2 - https://phppot.com/php/sending-email-using-phpmailer-with-gmail-xoauth2/

Comment: For any open source package, the first place to look should always be the docs. It's much faster than asking a question here and waiting for an answer. In this case, [it addresses exactly the question you're asking](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048347/unable-to-send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-through-phpmailer-getting-error-s

Use TLS instead. `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`.

Comment: As mentioned by CBRoe, Google indeed does not allow less secure apps to connect anymore.  If you were using this feature before, then you can carry on using it.  One of my accounts works fine, another does not.

Comment: With gmail now you need to create a app password to send emails and allow less secure apps no longer works. Look at instructions here: https://codecr8.com/2022/06/10/google-smtp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With gmail now you need to create a app password to send emails and allow less secure apps no longer works. Look at instructions here: https://codecr8.com/2022/06/10/google-smtp/

Basically you need to log into your gmail account and under security settings you need to enable 2 step verification. Once thats done you will need to generate a app password which will be the password used in your settings for the account password for smtp settings