# XAMPP send mail not working PHP

Tags: php, sendmail.exe

here are the details

**[php.ini]**

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header=Off
```

**[sendmail.ini]**

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=ssl
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=[email]@gmail.com
auth_password=[email password]
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=[email]@gmail.com
force_recipient=
hostname=smtp.gmail.com



 [mail function]
    mail('[email]@gmail.com','sample mail','sample content','From: anotheremail@gmail.com');
```

i have checked smtp settings properly, but its still not working please suggest.

Comment: show us your php code...

Comment: please check it @J.Zend i edit my question

Comment: did you get any error message?

Comment: check this out broo.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759419/using-gmail-smtp-to-send-email-with-php

Comment: thanks for the link@J.Zend but there is not any error message.

Comment: With google, you have to [allow less secure applications to use your account](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure SMTP on your server

You can use the googles free SMTP server Pretty easy to setup too.

```
<?php

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

//Send mail using gmail
if($send_using_gmail){
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username = "your-gmail-account@gmail.com"; // GMAIL username
    $mail->Password = "your-gmail-password"; // GMAIL password
}

//Typical mail data
$mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
$mail->SetFrom($email_from, $name_from);
$mail->Subject = "My Subject";
$mail->Body = "Mail contents";

try{
    $mail->Send();
    echo "Success!";
} catch(Exception $e){
    //Something went bad
    echo "Fail :(";
}

?>
```

You can try below as well.

You can send mail from localhost with sendmail package , sendmail package is inbuild in XAMPP. So if you are using XAMPP then you can easily send mail from localhost.

for example you can configure 
`C:\xampp\php\php.ini`and`c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini for gmail to send mail.`

in C`:\xampp\php\php.ini find extension=php_openssl.dll` and remove the semicolon from the beginning of that line to make SSL working for gmail for localhost.

in php.ini file find [mail function] and change

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = test@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
Now Open C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini. Replace all the existing code in sendmail.ini with following code

[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=test@gmail.com
auth_password=my-gmail-password
force_sender=test@gmail.com
```

//mail function

```
$mail=test@test.com
mail($mail, 'Subject', 'sample mail', 'From: test@axxx.ba');
```

Comment: still not sending any mail and even mail() function not showing any error, trying to get result from last two days@user3651819

Comment: i am using window8, is there any problem of version or sumthin else.

Comment: Yes I had the same problem on windows 8, could not make it working. I am using code above on win 7

Answer (score 2):

php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port=25
sendmail_path = C:/xampp/sendmail/sendmail.exe -t
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =
; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
;mail.force_extra_parameters =
; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header=On
; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;mail.log = syslog
```

Working For me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHPMailer instead:
download it from [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

copy the **PHPMailerAutoload.php** from the downloaded Zip folder & paste into your directory where you've your **contact us** page
Then paste the following code in your **contact page script**:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Don't forget to change the **dummy values**

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Windows and XAMPP, you have to replace the backslash `\` with `/` on your `php.ini` file. A sample value could be

`sendmail_path=C:/xampp/sendmail/sendmail.exe -t -i`

https://dzone.com/articles/how-send-emails-php-windows