# Php mail() function for gmail emails not working - SMTP and SMTP ports

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm trying to make a php form which sends a gmail email to someone through php form.

I expected the gmail to arrive, because I typed in the mail($to,$userSubject,$body);

It didn't work, however. I'm using visual studio code's php live server extension, because I just couldn't set it up with xampp control panel.

Some code:

```
$userName = $_POST['name'];
$userEmail = $_POST['email'];
$userSubject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "example@gmail.com";

$body = "";

$body .= "From: ".$userName. "\r\n";
$body .= "Email: ".$userEmail. "\r\n";
$body .= "Message: ".$message. "\r\n";
```

When I run the code from the form I get an error message:
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "smpt.gmail.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\kenefagijnica\webform.php on line 31

I tried to use ini_set(), but I don't know what parameters to use to change the port so that I am able to send gmails.

I also tried looking at the php.ini file but I don't know what to do for the Mailer.

Help, anyone?

Comment: please have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392371/mail-function-wont-send-email-error

Comment: Yes but... I'm not using xampp

Comment: oke.what you are using as server

Comment: Change port from 25 to any other from documentation - many ISPs block this port so that might be the reason you cannot connect

Comment: I downloaded an extension: PHP serverby brapifra . It works well but there's something wrong with either the code, or the ini_set() function

Comment: From my experience when I tested SMTP locally using XAMPP it worked but when taking it online to a GoDaddy server for example I encountered many issues (due to ports) and it did not work. Bottom line is that if you are using a hosting provider such as GoDaddy I would go with a Sendgrid API call using a bearer token.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Gmail SMTP to send email with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759419/using-gmail-smtp-to-send-email-with-php)

Comment: It doesnt sadly

Comment: I used ini_set('SMTP','gmail.com' );
ini_set('smtp_port',2525);
Yet It still displays the same error

Comment: What is on line 31 in webform.php?

Comment: Have you tried other ports or just `2525`? [Here's](https://www.mailgun.com/blog/which-smtp-port-understanding-ports-25-465-587/) a relatively short read about SMTP ports.

Comment: @JM-AGMS mail($to,$userSubject,$body);

it says that i must use ini_set(), yet every port cant connect?

Comment: @El_Vanja I have , but none display the same error message :
   mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "smpt.gmail.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()